# Should I declare variables accesed by a SerialPort's callback as synchronized?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a callback added to the `DataReceived` event of the `SerialPort`. This callback accesses some class' properties. So, must these properties be declared as `synchronized`? In other words, is possible that the main thread accesses a property while the callback is writing on it?

Here I put an example:

```
class A {
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] // <-- Is this necessary?
    public int Prop { get; set; }

    public A(SerialPort sp){
        serialPort = sp;
        serialPort.DataReceived += (Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) => {
            Prop++;
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: The `DataReceived` event runs on a threadpool thread, so it is quite possible for multiple threads to be accessing any data that you touch during that event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible but I don't know whether that actually happens because the code of the main thread is not visible here.

If two threads access Prop then it must be synchronized in some form. In this demo code the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` would be enough. But often you want to protect more state than just a single value. In that case you probably need to lock manually using `lock`.

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` is a code smell anyway. I believe it's there only for Java compatibility. 15 years ago Microsoft thought that people might want to migrate from Java to .NET a lot.

Comment: So, instead of `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` I should write the `get` and `set` methods of the property with the `lock` statement?

Comment: I'd probably do that just to not depend on the esoteric MethodImplOptions.Synchronized concept.